# Convert const wchar_t* into a WCHAR*

Tags: c++

How do I make this to work? C++ types are really confusing:

```
std::wstring wquery = std::wstring(query.begin(), query.end());
//split names
std::vector<WCHAR*> split_names;
std::stringstream ss;
ss.str(names);
std::string name;
while (std::getline(ss, name, ',')) {
    split_names.push_back(
        (
            std::wstring(
                name.begin(),
                name.end()
            )
        ).c_str()
    ); //error can't assign const wchar_t* into WCHAR*
}
```

Comment: What is `query` here? Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: they are not equal?

Comment: Why are you using `WCHAR`, and how is it defined.

Comment: The value returned by `c_str()` is a `const`, so the type contained by the `vector` also needs to be `const`. The pointer being pushed back is dangling, as the `wstring` object it is associated with is destructed.

Comment: Note that the way  you convert a `std::string` to a `std::wstring` only works for Latin-1 and subsets such as plain ASCII.

Comment: Also note that storing a pointer to a temporary yields a **dangling pointer**, that you'd better not use for anything.

Comment: Why not have a `std::vector<std::wstring>` instead of `std::vector<WCHAR*>`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf typedef wchar_t WCHAR;

Comment: @crashmstr The program is written that way I'm required to use  ´std::vector<WCHAR*>´

Comment: A practical solution to your problem, with the caveat about encoding noted above, is to make that a `std::vector<wstring>` (and remove the call to `.cstr()`)

Comment: @wasthishelpful its just a std::string I'm casting to std::wstring

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yeah I know, but then I'm required to cast std::vector<wstring> and its items to std::vector<WCHAR*> because the program is written that way.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho *because the program is written that way.* -- Isn't the reason why you're asking on SO is for us to change the program so that it works?  You are storing the address of a pointer that goes up in a puff of smoke on each iteration, plain and simple.  So the solution is *don't do that*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ tries to keep you from mistakes. Here:

```
std::wstring(name.begin(), name.end())).c_str()
```

you create a temporary object `std::wstring` and get the pointer to the string content. Object will be destroyed right after you leave this block. As a result you will get an invalid pointer.

**Don't** store pointer to the temporary object into your `std::vector<WCHAR*> split_names;`.

Comment: no, it's probablly because it's not `vector<const WCHAR*>`

Comment: Using `wcsdup(….c_str())` would be an option, only not a good one.

Comment: @appleapple is right, the detected error is not the future UB.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Mostly, first phrase was to address *C++ types are really confusing*.  In most cases type system with it's restrictions, like `const`, give the programmer a hint to think twice before doing something wrong.

Comment: @Kay Also there is a suspicious conversion between `std::string` and `std::wstring` is done here via `std::wstring(name.begin(), name.end()))`

Comment: @Nikita, it all begins with `stringstream ss`, why isn't it a wstringstream?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it rewriting everything to:

```
//split names
std::vector<std::wstring> split_names;
std::stringstream ss;
ss.str(names);
std::string name;
while (std::getline(ss, name, ',')) {
    split_names.push_back(std::wstring(name.begin(), name.end()));
}
std::vector<const WCHAR*> pszTags;
pszTags.resize(split_names.size());
for (int i = 0; i < pszTags.size(); i++)
    pszTags[i] = split_names[i].c_str();
```

Sorry for the inconvenience.